# Perixx PX-1100 keyboard LED button preventing screen lock

Tags: keyboard, lock-screen

I am using a Perixx PX-1100 backlit keyboard.  Pressing the LED button (which changes the backlight color) is registered as a mouse button click.  I have mapped these key presses to unknown by:

Creating 61-keyboard-local.hwdb in /etc/udev/hwdb.d containing:

```
evdev:input:b\*v04F2p0603\*
KEYBOARD_KEY_ff020001=unknown
KEYBOARD_KEY_ff020002=unknown
KEYBOARD_KEY_ff020003=unknown
KEYBOARD_KEY_ff020004=unknown
```

Then running:

```
sudo udevadm hwdb --update
sudo udevadm trigger /dev/unput/event*
```

This causes the system to no longer interpret this button as a mouse click.
HOWEVER, pushing this button is still interpreted as a repeating keypress with value unknown.  This causes the system idle timer to continuously reset preventing the screen lock from activating.  I have tried this using both Gnome 3 and KDE, and get identical results.

Is there a way to have the system completely ignore this key?